# Não estou conseguindo criar notificações com o plugin $cordovaLocalNotification usando o IONIC

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Tentei fazer baseado no código desse site: https://devdactic.com/local-notifications-ionic/

Mas quando aperto o botão "Add notification" aparece esse erro:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26771 ReferenceError: device is not defined
    at Scope.$scope.add (controllers.js:83)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:27615), <anonymous>:4:200)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65290
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30372)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30472)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:65289)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16764)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16752)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953)
    at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2942)
```

E quando aperto o botão "Is Scheduled" aparece esse erro:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26771 TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined
    at Object.isScheduled (ng-cordova.min.js:8)
    at Scope.$scope.isScheduled (controllers.js:97)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:27615), <anonymous>:4:224)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65290
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30372)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30472)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:65289)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16764)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16752)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953)
```

Pesquisando na internet descobri que o Cordova a partir da versão 4.0 para usar esse tipo de recurso precisa do Whitelist para acesso seguro a domínios externos não tenho certeza disso mas mesmo assim instalei esse plugin e ainda acrescentei no index.html essa tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos; *; style-src  &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; *">
```

e mesmo assim não funciona.

O template ficou assim:

```
<ion-content>
    <button class="button" ng-click="add()">Add notification</button>
    <button class="button" ng-click="isScheduled()">Is Scheduled</button>
</ion-content>
```

O Script ficou assim:

```
app.controller('AlarmeCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaLocalNotification, $ionicPlatform) {

  //Notificações locais do Alarme
  $scope.add = function () {
    var alarmTime = new Date();
    alarmTime.setMinutes(alarmTime.getMinutes() + 1);
    var sound = device.platform == 'Android' ? 'file:C:\Users\knot\Music\I Stand Alone (2014_12_11 04_07_36 UTC).mp3' : 'file://beep.caf';
    $cordovaLocalNotification.add({
      id: "1234",
      date: alarmTime,
      message: "This is a message",
      title: "This is a title",
      autoCancel: true,
      sound: sound,
    }).then(function () {
      console.log("The notification has been set");
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

O objeto cordova só é criado quando é testado em um dispositivo real ou emulado (como o AVD). O mesmo serve para o "device is undefined", device é uma propriedade do objeto global Window, que o cordova adiciona. Faça os testes emulando um ambiente ou executando diretamente em um dispositivo físico.

Se quiser testar para iOs, e não possuir um iPhone, aconselho usar o https://app.io/ 
. Nele você pode subir o seu app para uma nuvem e vê-lo funcionando como se fosse em um dispositivo

Comment: Estou tentando usar o emulador mas quando digito os comandos no terminal do node aparece isso:                                                                               **C:\Users\knot\Desktop\Alarme do Clima>ionic build android
Error: Unexpected token

C:\Users\knot\Desktop\Alarme do Clima>ionic emulate android
Error: Unexpected token

C:\Users\knot\Desktop\Alarme do Clima>** E já inclui as pasta "platform-tools" e "tools" no PATH do Windows. Tentei usar o genymotion só que fica do mesmo jeito e não posso usar meu celular no momento.

Comment: pode executar o comando "ionic info" e adicionar o resultado a sua resposta por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pela dica do IOS Ziro. Descobri que o meu projeto estava corrompido creio que foi na hora de salva no meu HD externo pois em vez de excluir o antigo para salvá-lo de novo eu apenas substituía os arquivos. Criei um novo projeto e copiei os arquivos que tinha feito da pasta www para ele e resolveu o problema.